# C1.Phone.RichTextBox.C1RichTextBox 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'?

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-8, richtextbox, componentone

I'm working with a custom RichTextBox which create small text blocks inside the TextBox. They are created with some text followed with a **Enter** or '**,**' key.
When creating a item with **Enter** or just when i entered some text, i can delete it with my **backspace** button. That works fine...

But when i create a item with some text followed by the '**,**', the item appears but i can't delete it with my **backspace**. I get a exception while trying to and i don't know why and how to solve this... The exception even occurs before the TextChanged event of the textbox.

Full exception:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> at C1.Phone.RichTextBox.C1RichTextBox.InnerTextChanged(Object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e) at C1.Phone.RichTextBox.C1RichTextBox._txtBox_TextChanged(Object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e) at MS.Internal.CoreInvokeHandler.InvokeEventHandler(Int32 typeIndex, Delegate handlerDelegate, Object sender, Object args) at MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent(IntPtr unmanagedObj, IntPtr unmanagedObjArgs, Int32 argsTypeIndex, Int32 actualArgsTypeIndex, String eventName)

Can someone help me out with this please?

Comment: Can you share the code that adds the text blocks?  Also, if `C1.Phone.RichTextBox.C1RichTextBox.InnerTextChanged` is a method you wrote, can you share that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @dbc i tried to manage it for the team to only accept the 'Enter' key. We noticed there is a small issue with the ',' key while accessing in the quick menu ( the Dot '.' submenu next to the enter ) the key will be processed as a dot. same as the other options in that menu